# Cannot change screen brightness on Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo G580

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, brightness

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo G580. My screen brightness remains at maximum(hotkeys work). I followed a previous post to modify grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

in the file `/etc/default/grub`
after this hotkeys should be functional.

The hotkeys stopped working but brightness was changing.However my system freezes 5 min after login. Please someone suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

Nothing after osi=" it works for me.